# Is is possible to call custom methods on other custom methods?

Tags: java, string, methods

I'm relatively new to Java here, and I'm exploring custom methods. I've coded a program where the user enters a string and it gets reversed. I'm trying to add another method to it to check if it's a palindrome(the same backwards and forwards like racecar).  Is it possible to call a custom method on a custom method then run in in the main?

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Done {
    public static String palindrome(String pal) {
        if (rev.equals(string)) {
            System.out.println("This string is a palindrome!");
            return string;
        }
    }

    public static String reverse(String string) {
        String rev = "";

        for (int i = 0; i < string.length(); i++) {
            rev = rev + (string.charAt(string.length() - (i + 1)));
        }

        System.out.println("Reversed String:");
        System.out.println(rev);
        palindrome(rev);
        return rev;
    }

    private static Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("REVERSATRON 2000");
        System.out.println();
        System.out.println("Enter string to reverse: ");
        reverse(scanner.nextLine());
    }
}
```

Thanks for the help!

Comment: Do you mean is it possible to call a method in another method? Yes, that's what you are doing in main..... Have you tried running it? Because it seems like it should work.....

Comment: I asked if its possible to create two methods, make one "piggyback" on the other one, and then run it all in the main.

Comment: As @Meepo mentioned, you're doing that.  The only thing here is to be clear about local variables, you can not share local variables among methods.

Comment: Yes that's totally fine. It's something you should be doing: breaking down large methods into smaller ones.

Comment: The reason your code is not working is because you are not always returning something in your palindrome method. I don't even think you need to return anything honestly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Methods can call as many methods as you want, and those methods can call even more methods. In fact, methods can even call themselves. I looked through your code and cleaned up some errors: this should work

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Done {
    public static void palindrome(String s, String rev) {
        if (rev.equals(s)) {
            System.out.println("This string is a palindrome!");
        }
    }

    public static void reverse(String s) {
        String rev = "";

        for (int i = 0; i < s.length(); i++) {
            rev = rev + s.charAt(s.length() - (i + 1));
        }

        System.out.println("Reversed String:");
        System.out.println(rev);
        palindrome(s, rev);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("REVERSATRON 2000");
        System.out.println();
        System.out.println("Enter string to reverse: ");
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        reverse(scanner.nextLine());
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks! It's really useful how you can network methods like that

Answer (score 0):

Yes! 
Methods are very helpful to break code down into segments. Calling methods within methods is *very* common as well. Infact, you've probably done it without realizing.

```
 public static void main(String args[]){
      ...
 }
```

Is  a method. So if you call a method within it, you are doing just that.

Additionally, you can use a method within itself (this is called recursion).